# Twitter Open Graph Dynamic images with only one URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter, facebook-opengraph

I have a serious problem with the use of Open Graph.
I have only one URL to share on Twitter : example.com/page?id=MY_ID

"MY_ID" is the ID of an image. This image need to appears on the summary of the Twitter Card when shared.

I tried to fill dynamically with JavaScript(jQuery) the og:image meta tag

```
$("meta[property='og\\:image']").attr("content", 'path/to/'+id+'.png');
```

(I checked, when I go manually on the URL, the og:image meta tag is successfully filled)

The fact is Twitter crawl into the HTML without execute JS (seems normal to me), so the crawler get my title, my description, but get an empty og:image content (because JS didn't fill with the crawler)

My current HTML meta tags :

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

If I put physically an image path in the og:image content, it works. But the users need to be able to share their own creations, not a generic image.

The other solution (used by Wordpress), would be to create a page/article for each creation, but hell no, if there is 10.000 creations, I don't want to have 10.000 pages related to.

Maybe I can try to generate the HTML on serverside, asking to twitter to go on a PHP script like "autoGenerate.php?id=MY_ID" then put all the meta tags and stuffs inside a variable and echo this variable at the end of the script...

Does someone have a solution for this problem ?
(I accept all the solutions, the ugly ones too :) )

Comment: You are generally right - server side rendering is the way to fix this problem... what technologies do you use for your server currently? There's usually some fairly light way to use a minimal template, and return the result as HTML with variables like meta-tags filled in based on a query string.

Comment: @arbuthnott thanks for the fast reply. I use from scratch PHP, without any rendering template like Blade or Twig

Comment: good news then, it should be easy to return exactly what you need without any new technologies. My php is rusty, but roughly you can just use the `id` key in your `$_GET` object to fill in the meta-tag. If nobody else answers, I'll look up the correct syntax and post an answer later.

Comment: Your PHP was good, but the solution didn't works. I tested the page, checked in the DOM, all meta tags are filled good, etc. No error, but Twitter continue to refuse to get the image. (The same problem exists with Google+ and LinkedIn). So I think I will wait for another solution because i'm running out of ideas ! T_T

Comment: Hmm... I think twitter may look for the tag `<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://somesite.com/someimage.jpg">`. You could try that syntax (as well as the `og:image`). We also use absolute urls, not relative. I'm not sure if that would make a difference, but worth a shot.

Comment: Twitter caches content for individual URLs for 7 days at a time, so unless each page is dynamically rendered on the server side and has a unique URL, this is unlikely to work.

Comment: Finally solved. I did a mistake : put an url in og:image and an image in og:url...

BTW, Without rendering serverside, it doesn't works.

With rendering serverside, it works, there is no cache content like Andy Piper said. (sorry man)

Answer (score 0):

Generate HTML serverside (with PHP) solved this problem...

Like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo "<html>\n";
echo "  <head>\n";
echo "        <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n";
echo "        <meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary\" />\n";
echo "        <meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"path/to/".$_GET['id'].".png\" />\n";
echo "        <meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"MY AWESOME TITLE\" />\n";
echo "        <meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"MY AWESOME DESCRIPTION\" />\n";
echo "        <meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"path/to/my-page.php?id=".$_GET['id']."\" />\n";
echo "        <title>TITLE OF THE PAGE</title>\n";
...
```